# Rank in the aggregate function

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate

Is it possible to rank the results in the `aggregate` function by one column?

For example if I have this long aggregate function and want to `rank(desc)` by `Survived`:

```
aggregate(Survived ~ Fare2 + Pclass + Sex, data=train, FUN=function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)})
```

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
result <- aggregate(Survived ~ Fare2 + Pclass + Sex, data=train, FUN=function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)})
result <- result[order(result$Survived,decreasing=T),]
```

This will give you the result in descending order of `Survived`.

Alternatively, you could add a rank column:

```
result      <- aggregate(Survived ~ Fare2 + Pclass + Sex, data=train, FUN=function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)})
result$rank <- rank(result$Survived)
result      <- result[order(result$rank,decreasing=T),]
```

BTW: You're just calculating the mean in the function, so you could use:

```
aggregate(Survived ~ Fare2 + Pclass + Sex, data=train, mean)
```